# How to display objects related to a specific foreign key object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to make a gaming app in which people create their teams and then create players and associate players to a specific team. The problem is how can I only display the players in a team that is connected with it.

Advance Thanks for your help.

Here,s my models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length =240)
   captain = models.CharField(max_length = 240)
   v_captain =  models.CharField(max_length = 240)

   def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('games_app:detail',kwargs = {'pk':self.pk})

   def __str__(self):
    return self.name    


class Players(models.Model):    
 over = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
 batting = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
 player_team = models.ForeignKey(Team,related_name = "teams")
```

Here,s the views.py

```
class List_Players(generic.ListView):
 model = models.Players
 template_name = 'games_app/players_list.html'
```

Here,s the HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
{% for i in object_list.player_team %}
<h1>Players :<strong>{{i.player_name}}</strong>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your view lists `Players` objects, not `Team`s. Also you seem to be confused about the `related_name` argument, it should be the other way around (i.e. `related_name="players"`). As a side note, consider renaming `Players` to `Player` as it will make more sense with Django's naming conventions.

Comment: why do you want teams view

Comment: and how would I address the real problem.

Comment: I don't want teams view, I am saying that your code does not agree with your question. What is the real problem? As I said it is unclear. You wrote that you want to `display the players in a team ` but your code seems irrelevant. Editing your question to include an example of expected output might help.

Comment: I have already written that i only wanna display those players who are connected with that team.

Comment: Do you want to show team member for each player in the `ListView`? That will lead to huge amount of redundant information. You should use `Team`'s `ListView` show members of each team, or show team members on `DetailView` of a `Player`.

Comment: I wanna show the players that are related to the team.For e.g Player1 is the part of team 1 so i want him to show only in team1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be like:--

```
 class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length =240)
    captain = models.CharField(max_length = 240)
    v_captain =  models.CharField(max_length = 240)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('games_app:detail',kwargs = {'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name    


class Players(models.Model):    
   over = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
   batting = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   player_team = models.ForeignKey(Team,related_name = "teams")
```

Here,s the views.py

```
class Team_list(generic.ListView):
  model = models.Team
  template_name = '''make a new template here'''
  context_object_name = 'team_list'

class List_Players(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Players
    template_name = 'games_app/players_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'team_detail'
```

Here,s the HTML

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1>{{ team_detail.name }}</h1>
   <h1>{{ team_detail.captain }}</h1>
   <h1>{{ team_detail.v_captain }}</h1>

   {% for players in team_detail.teams.all %}
   <h1>Players :<strong>{{players.over}}</strong></h1>
       {{ players.over }}
        {{ players.batting }}

   {% endfor %}
   </body>
   </html>
```

you have to make new Html file for your ListView of teams through which you can  link ur Detail view of whole team by using the  tag to the name of ur team

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
   {% for teams in team_list %}
   <h3>
      <a href='{% url 'TYPE IN UR URL NAME' pk=teams.pk %}'>{{ teams.name }}</a>
   </h3>

   {% endfor %}
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate over each `player` in the `object_list` and print out the team members of the team associated with it.

```
{% for player in object_list %}
    <p> {{player.player_name}} </p>
    {% for i in player.player_team.players %}
        <h1>Players :<strong>{{i.player_name}}</strong>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**But this is not at all recommended.**

That will lead to huge amount of redundant information. You should use `Team`'s `ListView` show members of each team, or show team members on `DetailView` of a `Player`. Consider to change the design of your page.

Comment: This doesn,t work . it shows all the players which are in db.

Comment: obviously, since you asked about the `ListView` of `Players`. I told you, you should use the `Team`'s `ListView`.